# Don't send exceptions to the client

Tags: python, rpc, autobahn

It seems that any except thrown in my WAMP server is caught by Autobahn and sent to the client.  There are two problems with this:  a) if something goes wrong on the server, it needs to be logged on the server so it can be fixed by the team, and b) those exceptions could potentially be very revealing (esp. exceptions from the ORM) and I don't want them to be forwarded to a malicious third party.

Can I prevent this behavior?  If I can, is there a way to explicitly send the error messages that *should* be sent to the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer**:

AutobahnPython no longer sends tracebacks by default.

When a procedure of a *Callee* is invoked that raises an exception, only the exception is forwarded - not a full traceback. To enable forwarding of tracebacks, set `traceback_app = True` on the *Callee's* `ApplicationSession`.

---

**Deprecated answer**: The following original answer does only apply to WAMP v1 code in AutobahnPython, which has been deprecated and removed.

> The last version of AutobahnPython with WAMP1 code was 0.8.15, which you can find [here](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/v0.8.15) and [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autobahn/0.8.15).

You can override the `onAfterCallError` hook on your class deriving from `autobahn.wamp.WampProtocol` (see [here](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/master/autobahn/autobahn/wamp.py#L389) or the generated docs).

In your override you can do your custom logging and/or modification of the error object that is the basis for the WAMP RPC error return sent to the caller.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  For those curious, here's a quick blog post I wrote about how I implemented this:  http://blog.luhn.com/post/53384559656/stop-autobahn-from-forwarding-exceptions-to-client

Comment: Great! Btw: turning off traceback sending in RPC error returns can also be done by setting `includeTraceback = False` on the protocol instance (https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/master/autobahn/autobahn/wamp.py#L506). I agree, it probably be should be off by default.

Comment: These links are 404ing.

Comment: @oberstet I just did a grep through the Autobahn source code and couldn't find `onAfterCallError` or `includeTraceback`. Have these methods changed? *edit* Looks like they have been removed from the repository, e.g. `wamp1/protocol.py`. Can we have an updated answer?

Comment: @GeraldKaszuba I've udpated the answer. You can check out implementation here https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/master/autobahn/autobahn/wamp/protocol.py#L150

Comment: @oberstet Thanks for that. I did see that variable earlier today, although I implemented a patch (which I'll send a pull request soon) which can offer the application session a choice to handle the error themselves, or to propagate it to the client.

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    main()
except Exception, e:
    log(str(e))
```

Comment: I would have to do that in every single RPC function I define.  I'm a programmer; I'm lazy.  Is there something I can do once and forget about it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Autobahn.  Other servers offer a way to do this once for all requests.  The real problem, though, is that exceptions are being generated in the code without any error handling.  There should really be specific "except" blocks for any code that could cause an exception, complete with logging.  It will make debugging a whole lot easier if you know where the error occurred.